# Trying to create a blurred background with text overlay where the text fill appears to de-blur the background but having trouble with alignment

Tags: html, css

Objective: Centered blurred "background" image with a text overlay, where the text "fill" appears to be transparent and showing the "background" image unblurred.

Status: I have created a div with the image centered on a black background and blurred. I have managed to overlay a separate div with an h1 and text, where the text's fill is the same original background image but unblurred.

Problem: I cannot figure out how to align the text's fill image with the original blurred "background" image so that it appears that the text is transparent and deblurring the background image. Instead the text fill image is offset from the background image and the overall effect is not achieved.

Code: https://codepen.io/unknown-error-event/pen/eYPKqWy

```
<div class="home-bg"></div>
<div class="home-name">
<h1>This is<br>Something</h1>
</div>
```

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.home-bg {
    width: 90%;
    height: 70%;
    background:  black url("https://i.ibb.co/mqZcxHx/monstera.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    filter: blur(12px);
    z-index: -1;
}

.home-name {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 70%;
    background: white url("https://i.ibb.co/mqZcxHx/monstera.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (testing on Safari, iPad) as long as the text is small enough to stay within the image, which at 60px it isn’t on narrow viewports. Try setting the size of the font to something more relative eg 8vmin. Also try setting the background non blurred to check things are fitting OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it would look, if you want to make sure it is in the correct position, remove the blur.I have also changed the height so that the text is not cut

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.home-bg {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background:  black url("https://i.ibb.co/mqZcxHx/monstera.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    filter: blur(12px);
    z-index: -1;
}

.home-name {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background: white url("https://i.ibb.co/mqZcxHx/monstera.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```